# Can be the indeterminate of a polynomial ring $R[X]$ be considered a special function?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can be the indeterminate of a polynomial ring $R[X]$ be considered a special function?

Im reading a bit about this topic and I see that you can define $X$ as

$$X:\Bbb N_0\to R,\quad n\mapsto \begin{cases}1,&\text{if }n=1\\0,&\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

Then $X\in R[[X]]= R^{\Bbb N_0}$, where $R[[X]]$ is a ring of formal power series over $R$, what mean that $X$ is not a polynomial, instead it is a formal power series that can be represented by the infinite vector

$$X=\langle0,1,0,0,0,...\rangle$$

But I dont understand why in [some sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_(variable)) it is said that $X$ is just a symbol or a placeholder.

If you can let to $X$ a functional definition, why stick to the confuse and vacuous meaning of "symbol" or "placeholder"? It is wrong my interpretation? Thank you in advance.